# JavaScript: translate long tap events to right click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch

How can one automatically translate long tap events to right click events? Since many touch devices like the iPad don't provide a way to do a right click on a website this would be very handy because a website's code doesn't need to be adjusted.

For example this code is designed for desktop browser having mouse support:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Long tap to right click test</title></head>
    <body>
        <img src="dummy.png" oncontextmenu="alert('Hi!'); return false;" width="20" height="20" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The goal is to translate a long tap event to the right click event without modifying the code. (Just loading some JavaScript, of course.)

If've seen that https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/ does something similar for drag'n'drop support on jQuery widgets. However this plugin doesn't support the long tap.

Also http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/ does actually perform the desired translation but it brakes scrolling, thus making it useless for regular websites with the need of scroll support.

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can write simple plugin to handle this type of events. Lets call it longTap event. Example:

```
$.fn.longTap = function(options) {

    options = $.extend({
        delay: 1000,
        onRelease: null
    }, options);

    var eventType = {
        mousedown: 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
        mouseup: 'ontouchend' in window ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup'
    };

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).on(eventType.mousedown + '.longtap', function() {
            $(this).data('touchstart', +new Date);
        })
        .on(eventType.mouseup + '.longtap', function(e) {
            var now = +new Date,
                than = $(this).data('touchstart');
            now - than >= options.delay && options.onRelease && options.onRelease.call(this, e);
        });
    });
};
```

Obviously you want to change `mousedown` and `mouseup` to `touchstart` and `touchend` in case of iPad.

Usage: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/RZgxT/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this solution requires that I have to modify all my website's code and call the longTap function on all elements with right click events. The problem is that no only my own code uses right click events but those are also triggered by some JavaScript plugins. I would have to go very deep to modify everything :-(.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout for that:

```
var timeoutLongTouch;
var $mydiv = $j('#myDiv');

// Listen to mousedown event
$mydiv.on('mousedown.LongTouch', function () {
    timeoutLongTouch = setTimeout(function () {
        $mydiv.trigger('contextmenu');
    }, 1000);
})
// Listen to mouseup event
.on('mouseup.LongTouch', function () {
    // Prevent long touch 
    clearTimeout(timeoutLongTouch);
});
```

Comment: Vielen Dank! Same as below: can this be more general so that I don't need use a selector on all elements that I want to make use of it but have a "global" translation?

Answer (score 0):

All solutions not work in desktop browsers.
You should also tune up 'click' handler behaviour, cause all 'longtap' events should also be followed by 'click' event.

In this case something code like this:

```
itemEl.click(function(event){

    if ($(this).data('itemlongtouch')){
        $(this).data('itemlongtouch', false);
    }else{
        //some work
    }
});

itemEl.longTap(function(event){
    $(this).data('itemlongtouch', true);
    //some work
});
```